# AJAX form submission issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

For some reason [the newsletter sign-up form bar I'm creating](http://t-zonevibration.com/topbar/index.php) is not working as it should in IE. In fact, it's not working at all. If you visit the link below in Chrome or Firefox it works like it should, but in any version of IE it doesn't.

Anyone have any leads to fix this?

Here's the code, summarized:

```
$(function() {
    $('#name').textboxhint({
        hint: 'First Name'  
    });
    $('#email').textboxhint({
        hint: 'Email Address'   
    });
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {  
        // VALIDATE AND PROCESS FORM
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email;
        // HANDLE DATA: SHOW ERROR IF FIELDS ARE BLANK
        if (name=='' || name=='First Name' ){           
            $('.errorIconName').show();
            return false;
        }
        if (email=='' || email=='Email Address'){   
            $('.errorIconEmail').show();
            return false;
        }
        else {          
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "#",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('#signupWidget').fadeOut(400).hide();
                $('#thankyouText').fadeIn(700).show();
                $('.errorIcon').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('#signupWrap').delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
                }       
            });
        }
        return false;
    });  
});
```

and...

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <span id="sprytextfield1" class="pr20">
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text"/>
        <div class="errorIconName" style="display:none"></div>
    </span>
    <span id="sprytextfield2" class="pr20">
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text"/>
        <div class="errorIconEmail" style="display:none"></div>
    </span>
    <span>
         <input type="submit" name="widgetButton" id="submitButton" value="SUBMIT"/>                
    </span>                
</form>
```

Comment: can you clarify what 'does not work' means? what happens when you click submit? Is it triggering any javascript errors?

Comment: The form in IE does not submit...the form does nothing (in IE). In Chrome, Firefox, etc, the success message will appear.

Comment: As already mentioned, have you tried using a URL that isn't `#`? That looks like the problem to me.

Comment: Duh! I'm an idiot. Didn't even notice that. Thanks for the help guys. It works now..